# MATLAB CNN Classification Different Results When Shuffled Columns

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, classification, feature-selection

I have applied 1D CNN on speech recognition, when I shuffled columns I got diffrent results, for example, using matrix(:,[1 2 3]) gives different classification results than matrix(:,[2 3 1]) which should be the same, I have tried rng("default")  but it hasn't resolved the issue. Can someone please assist me with this?
Thank you in advance!